# Eclipse RAP/RWT. Display.asyncExec() doesn't work correctly

Tags: user-interface, synchronization, swt, eclipse-rap

I have RAP/RWT application. The app has an implementation of `AbstractEntryPoint`. There is code:

```java
void createContent(Composite c){
    //...
    new Timer("status").scheduleAtFixedRate(createStatusTask(), 0, 5000);
}


TimerTask createStatusTask() {
    return new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getStatus();
        }
    };
}

void getStatus(){
    System.out.println("1");
    getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec(() -> {
        System.out.println("2");
        myLabel.setText("some new text")
    });
}
```

And when I start my app, I see the output:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
1
2
1
1
1
... and further "1" only
```

So, `myLabel.setText()` runs several times at the beginning and never more. It doesn't matter which method I use, `syncExec()` or `asyncExec()`.

Comment: For (a)syncExec to work in RWT you need to start a [Server Push session](https://eclipse.org/rap/developers-guide/devguide.php?topic=server-push.html&version=3.1). Have you done so?

Comment: Yes, I have tried with ServerPushSession and without it. It changes nothing.

Comment: If you can provide a [complete self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem, I suggest to [open a bug report](https://eclipse.org/rap/bugs/). Please post a link to the bug here, if you've done so.